# Excel 2016 vba macro to set borders to a cell range with filtered cells inside gives error (with Excel 2013 everything is fine)

Tags: excel, vba, border, cell

---- updated with more details ---

I have made a vba macro that works fine with Excel 2013, but have error with Excel 2016. The macro is very simple and is taken from "recorded macro": it set borders to some cells.

The problem (I suppose) is that cells included also filtered rows:

```
column_1 
cells(1;1) = "aa"
cells(2;1) = 2
cells(3;1) = 1
cells(4;1) = 2
cells(5;1) = 1
cells(6;1) = 1
```

filtered with "1" on the first row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHUdO.png)

So running the following macro,
you have error '1004' on ".weight " row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmi2w.png)

Giving OK you have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRpxv.png)

and if you stop the macro now and try to save the file,
you'll get an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8WdB.png)

**Please note that this happens only with Excel 2016, Excel 2013 has no problems**

This is the complete macro:
              Option Explicit

```
        Sub test()
            Sheets(1).Select
            Range("A1:A6").Select
            Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin   ' ==>>>>ERROR HERE
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
```

Please help
Thx

Comment: What is the error message? Not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: the error is "Error 1004"

Comment: The problem is that the same macro works fine with Excel 2013.

Comment: Macro works fine with Excel 2019 too.

Comment: Do you test it with Excel 2016 ?

Answer (score 0):

Change range and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code is tested and works perfectly. In my opinion you code gives an error because you dont refer to specific sheet, instead you are using .Select

Comment: It works with Excel 2013, so refefence to Sheet(1) doesn't change the result. (I testd it just now)

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading Microsoft documentation and it seems the selection is unneccesary. Try this:

```
sub test()

Range("A1:A6").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

With Range("A1:A6").Borders(xlEdgeLeft)

.LineStyle = xlContinuous

.ColorIndex = 0

.TintAndShade = 0

.Weight = xlThin   ' ==>>ERROR HERE

End With

End sub
```

You may have to throw ActiveWorksheet before the range or a Sheet( "Sheet1") depending on what sheet you are on when the macro runs. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, but not ;-(